# Unit root quantile autogression in python

Tags: python, quantile-regression

I'm working with a QAR model and searching for a documentation or code-example in Python. I'm specifically looking for the Python implementation of the methods of Koenker and Xiao (2004).

Answer (score 0):

try this one,
Unit root quantile auto regression resource : https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/quantile-regression-in-python#:~:text=In%20ordinary%20linear%20regression%2C%20we,term%20in%20the%20linear%20model.